# Unexpected value of current time after creating end time

Tags: javascript

I have these lines of code:

```js
const start = new Date();
const end = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 7);
console.log(start, new Date(), end);
```

The `end` is set correctly and it's a week ahead.

**BUT** The `start` time (which is the current time) unexpectedly gets equal to the `end` time?!

I never assigned the `start` to anything but the `new Date`!!

Why and How to fix this?

Comment: You should read the documentation for [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), specifically that it "changes the day of the month of a given Date instance". The name `setDate` itself is also a big clue as to its behavior.

Comment: Simply use `const end = new Date().setDate(start.getDate() + 7);`

Comment: @Thanks Chris G... Good Answer....

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+date+and+copy+are+the+same) of [Javascript date variable assignment](/q/6609574/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

setDate function change the object Date. In your case it's changed the start.

```
const start = new Date();
const end = new Date();
end.setDate(start.getDate() + 7);
console.log(start, new Date(), end);
```

Const doesn't have sense here either.